# Appium is not supporting Android 7.1

Tags: android, appium, android-7.1-nougat

I am using Appium Version 1.4.16 in Windows 7,

When I try to connect Android with OS 7.1 getting below error,

```
 A new session could not be created. (Original error: Command failed: C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /s /c "C:\Users\Devendran\Downloads\Android_SDK\platform-tools\adb.exe -s 84B7N16411007687 install "C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\build\settings_apk\settings_apk-debug.apk""
Failed to install C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\build\settings_apk\settings_apk-debug.apk: Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_ALREADY_EXISTS: Attempt to re-install io.appium.settings without first uninstalling.]
) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 19.02 seconds
Build info: version: '2.53.1', revision: 'a36b8b1', time: '2016-06-30 17:37:03'
System info: host: 'Wipro-Laptop', ip: '192.168.0.230', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_05'
Driver info: io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:408)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:206)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:158)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:678)
    at io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileDriver.execute(DefaultGenericMobileDriver.java:40)
    at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.execute(AppiumDriver.java:1)
    at io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver.execute(AndroidDriver.java:1)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:249)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:131)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:144)
    at io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileDriver.<init>(DefaultGenericMobileDriver.java:36)
    at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.<init>(AppiumDriver.java:114)
    at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.<init>(AppiumDriver.java:132)
    at io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver.<init>(AndroidDriver.java:92)
    at StartApplication.main(StartApplication.java:42)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at StartApplication.main(StartApplication.java:65)
```

Can anyone help here.

Comment: Logs from Appium:

Answer (score 1):

This is caused by an old bug that has been recently fixed.
What you need to do, is to update Appium to the latest version and restart the server.

Instructions here: https://github.com/appium/appium/issues/6665#issuecomment-254269722